# How to filter via laravel relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

Could someone help me if I can filter through laravel relationship in following scenario? I want to filter with the slip id / or customer_id/ or customer name.

```
public function search_index($query){
        $slip = Slip::with('customer')
            ->where('slip_id',$query)
            ->orWhere('customer.id',$query)
            ->orWhere('customer.name',$query)->get();
}
```

Edit:
there are two classes: Slip and Customer. With the relations being slip belongs to customer and customer has many slips.

The slip contains other information including customer id and customer is retrieved using 'customer' relationship. Now I want to be able to find the slips by either entering customer name/id or slip id.
($query) may have one of those details

`Slip::with('customer')` returns details in following pattern:

```
[{slip:{id:1, ref:'abc', customer:{id:1,name:'Joe'}},}]
```

I want the query to return result in similar fashion too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you want your filtered result to be?  And where `$query` value is assigned?

Comment: @HuyPhạm I elaborated in the edit please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't execute the code, but I pretty sure that this is gonna work.

```
$slip = Slip::query
    ->whereHas('customer', function(Builder $q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('id', $query) //Search by customer id
                 ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%'); //search by customer name similiarity
    })
    ->orWhere('id', $query) //search by slip_id
    ->get();
```

This is not the best practice as I would suggest. It is recommended that you should break down the query in to 3 smaller functions/module, then get their `intersect()` as final result.